# How can get dynamic image in scripts on wp

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

How can I dynamic or query in wp this type of script for every single post?

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {   
           mast.init(); 
          $("#laptop").rollerblade({
              imageArray : [
                rootPath + 'macbook/front.png',
                rootPath + 'macbook/front-side-right.png',
                rootPath + 'macbook/side-right.png',
                rootPath + 'macbook/back-side-right.png',
                rootPath + 'macbook/back.png',
                rootPath + 'macbook/back-side-left.png',
                rootPath + 'macbook/side-left.png',
                rootPath + 'macbook/front-side-left.png'
            ],
            sensitivity : 50,
            drag : true
        });
    });

</script>
```

I need to get rootPath image dynamically in wordpress.

Comment: why WordPress, if that is JavaScript ? how do you plan to handle that ?

Answer (score 0):

if you are new to jQuery and wordpress, first you will want to change your jQuery references from the $ to jQuery.

Next, you can change your header.php for the theme to output the rootpath

```
<script>
var rootPath = <?php site_url(); ?>;
</script>
```

Now, if what you really want is the URL to your theme...it would change slightly.

```
<script>
var rootPath = <?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>;
</script>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/site_url
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri